# How to disable weights in pyvis.network graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pyvis

I have plotted a graph using `pyvis.network` like the following:

```
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'Node1', target='Node2')
net = Network(notebook=True)
net.from_nx(G)
net.show('BRCA_sigpairs.html')
```

However, the resulting graph has a value of one on every edge like the following:
[image]
How can I disable these values on the edges? I tired to set `edge_attr` argument in the `nx.from_pandas_edgelist()` function as `None` or `0` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you share sample df? i reproduced your code using karate club graph and its not showing these weights.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter `edge_attr=None`:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'Node1', target='Node2', edge_attr=None)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried it and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
i was not used `from_pandas_edgelist()`

```
edges = nx_graph.add_edge(cur_node, neighbor_node, weight='')
```

I solved this problem to add `weight=''`.

I want to solve the problem in this way